# Fast way to get SQLite single column result to list

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the list of words with additional columns in my SQLite DB. I want to just get the list of words (basically single column). Below is the code how I am doing it.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select word from wordlist", null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    words.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("word")));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
```

It works but its slow. For example, for about 100K words, it takes close to 1 sec. However, if I just have the list of words in the text file, it can be read in ~100ms.

Is there any way to read the single column from the SQLite DB directly into the list instead of getting the cursor and iterating over it to get all the values? If not, what is the better solution? Simply go back to the text file instead?

Comment: There might be a bulk select feature in SQLite, but in general, in Java this is how you iterate a result set.  Note that 1 second for 100K records sounds pretty fast to me.

Comment: Your cursor has only 1 column so replace: `c.getColumnIndex("word")` with `0`. Maybe you see a difference for 100K calls of the same method.

Comment: in addition to @forpas comment, it would be more elegant just to store the column index to variable like `int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex("word");` right before `do..while`, and use variable instead of getting column index each iteration, or using magic number.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I tried all these but the performance gain is not noticeable. As such I guess, compilers might already be doing such optimizations. I'm looking for ways to get significant performance improvement, not just a few milliseconds!

Answer (score 0):

i don't have a performance problem, so i can't be bothered to try this, but how does something like this perform? the idea is to ensure the buffer (`CursorWindow`) is fully utilized and then to read directly from that buffer instead of letting the cursor mediate. `CursorWindow` even has a constructor that allows you to override the default buffer size, in case you're inclined to experiment with that.

i'm fairly confident that this is as close to sqlite as android will let you get, so if something like this doesn't improve things, you have to either bundle your own sqlite or use a different storage mechanism.

```
try(Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select word from wordlist", null))
{
    c.setFillWindowForwardOnly(true);
    CursorWindow window = new CursorWindow("nameForDebugging");
    c.setWindow(window);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        int index = 0;
        do
        {
            int count = window.getNumRows();
            for(int x = 0; x < count; ++x)
                words.add(window.getString(index++, 0));
        } while((count != 0) && c.moveToPosition(index));
    }
}
```